# Date Range Search in Lucene 4.0

Tags: java, date, search, lucene, range

I have a situation where I need to search data between range of two dates(including lower and upper values) in LUCENE 4.0.
I have a field in the indexes which has a String value in the format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS". Now I need to make a search between a date range. But I am not getting the result that I am expecting. Below is My code-

```
String startValue = "2008-01-01 00:00:45";
String endValue = "2016-02-10 00:00:00";
Query query = new TermRangeQuery("Field51",  new BytesRef(startValue), new BytesRef(endValue), true, true);
//Final Query for Search
Final Query for Search  :  Field51:[2008-01-01 00:00:45 TO 2016-02-10 00:00:00]
129 documents found. Time taken :93 milli seconds.
```

The above query gives me the result starting from 2009. Any date that lies between 2008 and 2009 is skipped. So if my start date has a Year 2010, then result that i will get will be from 2011.

One solution would be to index my date fields in milliseconds, so that i can perform numeric search. But i don't want to change the format of my date.

I have iterated the hits and converted the result into ArrayList of HashMap, which seems like below,

```
[{Field51=2009-09-06 13:58:09}, {Field51=2009-02-02 13:51:14}, {Field51=2009-01-17 08:11:02}, {Field51=2009-09-29 12:55:34},....
```

I have 129 results, but none of the result has a date of year 2008. Whereas I have data with year as 2008.

[Image of CSV File that is being indexed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGu3I.jpg)

Comment: It would be necessary to know how you have indexed the field. Got a suspicion, though, that you are also getting all results from 2016, rather than just the ones from *January* in 2016. I'd strongly recommend you take a look at [DateTools](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/DateTools.html).

Comment: Basically I am moving my data from mqsql to lucene. For this I am exporting my data into a csv that may contain millions of data. Now each row in a csv is a unique record to me, identified by a unique column, and first row is the header. So I pick up the header, save it in ArrayList, and read next 1000 records at a time, process it to create Indexes. My header is the field and data in the row are the values.For each row I make a pair of Header Fields and current row values. For each row processed, i give a unique doc Id to it which is nothing but the unique value in each row. PFA screen shot.

Comment: What is the field type of this field when you're indexing (inserting)?
If it's TextField for example, then the analyzer splits text into tokens, (so 2009-09-06 and 13:58:09 will be two tokens), so naturally querying will not work.
I think you should convert to milliseconds and use a LongField to make querying and Indexing more efficient.

Comment: I found the solution. I have converted my date(Format : YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) to String using `DateTools.dateToString` before Indexing.
While Searching, I search for Date in `Long` and then I convert my dates back to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format using `DateTools.stringToDate`.